# NHibernate - SchemaExport Tool Question?

Tags: nhibernate, schemaexport

Is it posible to control what objects get generated when using the SchemaExport tool. For example if I have NH mapping files for an EntityA, EntityB, and EntityC how can I exclude C from being created?

Roberto.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can use the SchemaUpdate instead of the SchemaExport, the SchemaUpdate will udpate only the schema.

Or if you use NH 2.1 you can add the schema-action="none" to your mapping :

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/12/15/customizing-schema-export-with-schema-action.aspx

Comment: Thanks Matthieu but I was hoping to get something working with NH 2.0.1.

Comment: As 2.1.0GA has been released I guess I should accept this.  Thanks again Matthieu.